# How to reduce the filter options from the defaultColDef in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to incorporate AG-Grid in my Angular app. I am using the defaultColDef which provides a lot of filter option namely: contains, not contains, starts with, ends with, equals, and not equals. I only need three which are starts with, equals, and contains.

```html
<div *ngIf="tableOption">
  <ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-alpine" id="ag-grid" 
    [pagination]="true" 
    paginationPageSize=10 
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    domLayout='autoHeight' 
    [columnDefs]="ColumnHeader" 
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
    [enableRangeSelection]="true" 
    [rowSelection]="rowSelection" 
    [rowGroupPanelShow]="rowGroupPanelShow" 
    [pivotPanelShow]="pivotPanelShow">
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

I tried to set filter options in my component but it is not taking effect.

```ts
 public columnTitles = [{
     field: 'importance',
     maxWidth: 120,
     valueGetter: 'node.Importance',
     cellRenderer: 'loadingCellRenderer',
     sortable: true,
     suppressMenu: true,
     filter: 'ImportanceFilter',
     filterParams: {
       filterOptions: ['equals', 'contains', 'startsWith']
     }
   }
   //,...
 ];

 constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private singleUrlService: SingleUrlService,
   private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   this.defaultColDef = {
     enableRowGroup: true,
     enablePivot: true,
     enableValue: true,
     sortable: true,
     resizable: true,
     flex: 1,
     minWidth: 150,
     filter: true,
     enableRangeSelection: true,
     pagination: true,
     filterOptions: ['equals', 'contains', 'startWith']
   };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `filterOptions` on the `defaultColDef` object, whereas you need to set the `filterParams` on `defaultColDef`. Try the following:

```
this.defaultColDef = {
  enableRowGroup: true,
  enablePivot: true,
  enableValue: true,
  sortable: true,
  resizable: true,
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: 150,
  filter: true,
  enableRangeSelection: true,
  pagination: true,
  filterParams: {
      filterOptions: ['equals', 'contains', 'startWith']
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @SprintIsLove if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.